# dynamically addressing a classes variables

Tags: java, xml, class, variables, dynamic

I am not too sure I can do this, but I'd like to.  I am reading in an XML file and on some of the nodes there are a good number of attributes that I end up storing in variable inside of an object.  Currently, I parse through the nodes, get the attribute names and then go through a very large of if/then/elses to be able to store it in the correct object variable.  All of this works just fine.

What I would like to be able to do is do it a little more dynamically, have a mapping mechanism that maps the attribute name to the variable name in the object.
So, for example, if I have a node   , I could map the data to say, object.city and object.addr in my object without having to have a hardcoded if/then for each attribute I capture.  I have several nodes/objects I do this for, and although it doesn't change that often, I think it would be cleaner to map it like I described.

Is something like that even possible in Java ?

many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can access fields and methods of a class using the [Reflection API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/index.html). But if your goal is only to read an XML file, don't reinvent the wheel -- just use an existing library such as [JAXB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding).

Answer (score 1):

There are many POJO-XML mapping utilities. Apache's XML beans and Sun's JAXB are two common ones.

Here is an XMLBeans tutorial: http://xmlbeans.apache.org/documentation/tutorial_getstarted.html

Comment: Note:  JAXB is actually a standard (JSR-222) with multiple implementations:  Metro JAXB (the reference implementation), EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy), Apache JaxMe, etc.